# How to convert a python list with string element without quotes to a proper list?

Tags: python, string, list

Consider this list:

```
list1 = [home , school, ground, field]
```

As you can see that the elements of list are string without quotes, so this is an invalid list. Is there any way to convert this to proper list using python?
The list should look like this:

```
list1 = ['home' , 'school', 'ground', 'field']
```

Comment: Unless those are variable names. That isn't valid code.

Comment: If you literally have a list `list1 = [home , school, ground, field]`, you'll get `NameError` simply trying to run the code.

Comment: Where is `list1 = [home , school, ground, field] ` coming from? Are you reading it from a text file or standard input? As others have said that line is not valid in a Python script unless `home`, `school`, etc are variables that already exist.

Comment: If it is `'[home , school, ground, field]'`, then you can use `split(',')` to get a valid list

Comment: I know the code will give error, I just want to know if there is any method or module to convert list1 to proper python list. Thank you.

Comment: No, those are not variables @PM 2Ring

Comment: If that line is in a Python script then the script won't run, due to the SyntaxError, so it won't be able to do anything.

Comment: As @PM2Ring where does it come from? You will be able to create this list of strings without going via this intermediate list of variable names

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: Well you cannot convert something which is invalid syntax. Maybe you mean having the string list1 = "[home , school, ground, field]" and converting it to a list. You can use `list1[1:-1].split()`  (The [1:-1] gets rid of the opening and closing keys)

Comment: But if you are reading that as a string from some text file (or user input), then you can easily create a valid list.

Comment: @PM2Ring *"If that line is in a Python script then the script won't run, due to the SyntaxError"* You're using undefined variables but it's still syntactically correct.

Comment: @Tagc Good catch! You are perfectly correct. That line will raise `NameError`, not `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, technically you can do it like this:

```
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        list1 = [home , school, ground, field]
    except NameError as e:
        varname = str(e).split("'")[1]
        locals()[varname] = varname
    else:
        done = True

print(list1)
# ['home', 'school', 'ground', 'field']
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

Maybe you could write a decorator that turns every `NameError` into a variable and re-runs whatever scope the code was run in, hopefully a function... but honestly... you're just going to turn your code into an unmaintainable, complicated mess.

Also, how would this code get written in the first place? Unless your scripts are templates which are generated by other programs... in which case, why not generate them correctly? :P

Comment: Evil, but cute. ;)

Comment: what are the consequences of using this